# yasnippet and evil mode : how to switch to normal mode without exiting the snippet environment

Tags: linux, emacs, elisp, snippets, evil

The problem is when I am in a snippet expansion, I hit escape to switch to normal mode, and the snippet is escaped. 
How can I make it to behave like this:
one escape only switch to evil normal mode, two consecutive escape exit the snippet environment.

What is the command escape runs when I am inside a snippet expansion?

Thank you for your help.